# The type or namespace name 'FriendlyUrls' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I have a simple WebForms project on VisualStudio 2013 created with standard web project wizard. Recently, I ve installed VisualStudio 2015 and decided to upgrade. After upgrade, I ve run standard NuGet package restore, which went just fine.

To my surprise the project does not build. Error message is:

> The type or namespace name 'FriendlyUrls' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet'

1. I ve looked into references section: Yes, proper reference is really missing there.
2. I ve looked into installed NuGet packages: Yes, proper package is installed in place and updated to the latest version.
3. I ve explicitly uninstalled the package with NuGet and installed it again: No change. Error is still the same.

In fact, I can build project successfully with 'FriendlyUrls' uninstalled. But, of course, proper functionality is missing then. Maybe somebody may have more ideas what can be done in this situation to fix the project?

Comment: If you're sure the package is correctly installed, it's compatible (fw version compatibility) and it just misses the reference you can edit the scproj and add manually it, it looks like this: <Reference Include="(full assembly name)">
      <HintPath>(path to the dll on downloaded packages)</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>

Comment: @Gusman, Thank you for the suggestion. It was the first thing I have tried. Moreover, I navigated to installed package folder in project package store, just to discover that there is simply no assembly DLL inside it, which I can reference explicitly. I really wonder, if I m first to upgrade in this typical scenario or others had this issue before and resolved somehow?

Comment: I had this problem once, and it was because the package was designed for a higher FW version. Does it not complain at all when you add the nuget package? try to add it from the package console instead of the nuget manager, it will tell you if there's any incompatibility or problem

Comment: @Gusman, Please write your suggestion as a solution. I ve installed package from command line and it fixed the build. Is it a bug of visual NuGet manager? I ve compared output log of NuGet in both versions and found no difference. Both have run without warnings. But visual install produced corrupted installation.

Comment: Oh man, I remember now why it happens. That's because the nuget management system changed from 2013 to 2015, with 2013 you had to have the .nuget folder with the executables and the project has some targets wich will fail on 2015, 2015 does not need any of these at all as it's done by VS itself. Let me search for the doc which explains it and I will add the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem some time ago, the project wont compile and packages aren't really restored.

That's because the nuget management system changed on VS2015 from MS-build restore to Automatic Package restore.

You can use the package console to install it, but is better to follow these instructions provided by nuget: [Migrating to automatic restore](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore).

Comment: You can add -t:restore to the msbuild parameter list to solve TFS issues too